# Как сделать QSplitter видимым?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qss, qsplitter

`QSplitter` по умолчанию невидим.

Я находил советы, в которых нужно было добавить "всего 20 строчек кода" для отображения разделителя, но мне кажется это можно сделать проще.

Подскажите пожалуйста как?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()

splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Поле 1')
label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('Поле 2')
splitter.addWidget(label1)
splitter.addWidget(label2)

vbx = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
vbx.addWidget(splitter)
window.setLayout(vbx)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: splitter по умолчанию не отображается]

Comment: А если попробовать setHandleWidth(1)?

Comment: Нет, к сожалению разделителя всё ещё не видно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()

splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)

splitter.setStyleSheet("""
QSplitter::handle:vertical {
    height: 2px;
    background-color : red;
}
""")

label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('окно 1')
label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('окно 2')
splitter.addWidget(label1)
splitter.addWidget(label2)

vbx = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
vbx.addWidget(splitter)
window.setLayout(vbx)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @arachnoden то, что я предложил, вам подходит ?

Comment: Да, спасибо, то что искал.